# How to get the first items of a group in dask.DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I want to get the first item of each set of different entries of a columns containing IDs. It works with pandas, but not in dask, as I cannot sort with multiple columns and the `.head` aggregation is not implemented. Is there another way of getting the desired result?

Here is the mimimal example for pandas, where everything works fine

```
import pandas as pd

t=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,"ij"],[1,2,"huHU"],[2,4],[2,9],[0,17],[0,2],[1,8],[1,-18]],columns=["particleID","distZ","someothercols"])
tz = ( 
        t
        .sort_values(["particleID","distZ"],axis=0)
        .groupby(["particleID"])
        .head(1)
    )
print(t)
print(tz)
```

But in dask, see below, I get a `NotImplementedError`.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

t2=dd.from_pandas(t,npartitions=2)
tz2 = ( 
        t2
        .sort_values(["particleID","distZ"],axis=0)
        .groupby(["particleID"])
        .head(1)
    )

print(t2.compute())
```

I could get the pandas result with this code, but it seems quite inefficient, since I have a needless sort first. Also, in my real application, I need more then one row per group and head does not work with dask

```
tz2 = ( 
        t2
        .sort_values(["distZ"],axis=0)
        .sort_values(["particleID"],axis=0)
        .groupby(["particleID"])
        .first()
    )

print(t2.compute())
print(tz2.compute())
```

Background: I want to convince everyone to with from SAS to python and pandas. However, we have some very large datasets and this is a very common application. In SAS it is quite easy with `if first`.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the `NotImplementedError` is raised by `.sort_values` since right now `dask.dataframe` only implements sorting on a single column value, see [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I know that for a fact, that’s why I am asking how to do the desired calculation in dask.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is [dask.groupby.apply](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) with a function that works on a DataFrame of each group.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

t2=dd.from_pandas(t,npartitions=2)
tz2 = ( 
        t2
        .sort_values(["particleID"],axis=0)
        .groupby(["particleID"])
        .apply(lambda s: s.sort_values(["distZ"],axis=0).head(2),
            meta={"particleID":"int", "distZ":"int", "someothercols":"object"})
    )
print(t2.compute())
print(tz2.compute())
```